# HeadlessExperimental in Puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) and I'd like to access the [HeadlessExperimental](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/HeadlessExperimental) domain.

I can enable the domain, but if I try calling [beginFrame](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/HeadlessExperimental#method-beginFrame), I get this error message:

```
content-generator-api-0  | Error: Protocol error (HeadlessExperimental.beginFrame): 
Command is only supported if BeginFrameControl is enabled.
```

Here is the code I'm running

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(...)
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(url)
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await cdp.send('HeadlessExperimental.enable')
const frameData = await cdp.send('HeadlessExperimental.beginFrame', {screenshot: {}})
```

I have the following chromium flags set, as suggested in ["Rendering in Headless Chrome"](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PppegrpXhOzKKAuNlP6XOEnviXFGUiX2hop00Cxcv4o/edit#)

```
'--enable-surface-synchronization',
'--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw',
'--disable-threaded-animation',
'--disable-threaded-scrolling',
'--disable-checker-imaging',
```

Judging by a description found in the [chromium.org forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/scheduler-bugs/NQnhuAFmcwI/B1jQcNF8BAAJ), my guess is that I'll need to modify the Puppeteer lib to support creating targets with BeginFrameControl.

> Currently, the BeginFrameControl is only supported in headless mode
>   and can only be enabled at target creation time.

Also, the stable release of Puppeteer is running chromium revision 594312, but it looks like the HeadlessExperimental wasn't patched in until [612061](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/612061/16), which isn't included in any of the [current chromium releases](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `--enable-begin-frame-control` switch to chrome launch parameters